# Jekyll - unable to get the url and the name of the author

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to fetch author details to display near their blog with the following code

```
{% assign author = site.authors | where: 'name', post.author %}
{% if author %}
- <a href="{{ author.url }}">{{ author.name }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

while i try to print the author using {{ author }} it displays the author page in the view, but while i try to print anything like {{author.url}} or {{author.name}} it doesn't print anything.

Also while i separately print the author details with the following code it displays the details

```
{%- for aut in site.authors-%}
{{aut.name}}
{{aut.url}}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% assign author = site.authors | where: 'name', post.author %}
```

This returns an array containing matching elements or `nil` if no matching element is found.

If matching element is supposed to exist and be unique, you can get it by using the [first](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/first/) array filter like this :

```
{% assign author = site.authors | where: 'name', post.author | first %}
```